# BeforeBuild event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, msbuild

I have the following in my .csproj file:

```
<Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  <Message Text="##########TESTING####################" Importance="high" />
</Target>
```

But it's not being outputted. I also changed my build output verbosity to Normal and then Detailed (As I have seen this in other posts).

I can see this from the verbose output:

```
Target "BeforeBuild" in file  "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets" from project "C:\MyPath\MyProj.csproj" (target "Build" depends on it):
Done building target "BeforeBuild" in project "MyProj.csproj".
```

I'm not sure what else I need to check to make sure it fires.

Note: The build isn't successful as the BeforeBuild event is meant to add some files in to build based on a config file (not included in my example) so could this be having an impact? I assumed that because it's BeforeBuild it should run whether the build is successful or not.

Edit: Just tried on a successful build and still no output.

Answer (score 0):

Ok .. I guess it's too early.

When you change the Build event in your `.csproj` file (especially when using notepad as no syntax highlighting) remember to remove the comment tags surrounding it ....

Comment: Using notepad will cause this :) I always edit MSBuild files with VS.

Comment: Yeah, tell me about it. One of those days I think :)